# How to catch exceptions when using DataFrameWriter to write dataframe with JDBC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a dataframe to a MySQL database. The database is throwing a `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry 'qwer1234' for key 'transaction_id_UNIQUE'`.

The code that I am using to write to the database is

```
txnsDF.write.mode("append").jdbc(connProp.getProperty("url"), query, connProp)
```

Now I can't really write a try catch around this because it is not on a row level and looking at the org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils class it inserts batches of 1000 transactions at a time.

I could remove the constraint on the database but that doesn't really solve my problem of handling exceptions coming from this class.

My last option, would be to partially rewrite the savePartition method in JdbcUtils to handle the exception and I really don't want to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not fix your code? Why are you inserting duplicate keys?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but that doesn't really address what I am trying to accomplish, which is figure out how to catch exceptions and handle them appropriately when communicating to the database. Whether it a connection time out or a Duplicate entry, I should be able to catch those and handle them gracefully rather than having the application fail because of one Duplicate entry. Catch it, log it, move on. If I'm processing 100 million lines and inserting them into the database then I really don't want to have to restart if the application fails on the second to last batch insert.

Comment: Also, let me note that I am on Spark 1.6.2

Comment: I agree that it doesn't solve the problem. But given the code example it does raise the question. Perhaps you want to emphasize that you're generally looking for way to log exceptions